# Use of uninitialized value within @arr in perl

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script which reads a directory containing my SQL file.

Then iterating over this array and removes one of them and prints them out.

```
@sqlArray = glob('C:/Users/Geeks/Folder/*.sql');

print Dumper(@sqlArray );

if( $company ne 'Geeks'){
  my $index = 0;
  my $count = scalar @sqlArray ;
  $index++ until $sqlArray [$index] eq 'factura.sql' or $index==$count;
  splice(@sqlArray , $index, 1);
}

print Dumper(@sqlArray );
```

I get following error which I don't know how does it come and how to fix it?

```
Use of uninitialized value within @sqlArray in string eq at /.../software/Queries.pl line 97.
```

Any Idea welcome and thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a very complicated way of doing `@sqlArray = grep { $_ ne 'factura.sql' } @sqlArray`.

Comment: Also, this seems like an [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: uninitialized value within an array means the element you are trying to use doesn't exist. You used the last one and then tried to use the next one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  my $count = scalar @sqlArray ;
  $index++ until $sqlArray [$index] eq 'factura.sql' or $index==$count;
```

`$count` is the size of the array. The last index in the array is therefore `$count-1`. Your code is trying to access the indices `$count` and `$count+1` though, which are undefined. Better:

```
  $index++ until $index==$count-1 or $sqlArray[$index] eq 'factura.sql';
```

or maybe easier to understand:

```
  $index++ while $index<$count and $sqlArray[$index] ne 'factura.sql';
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you visited one element beyond the end of the array. The array has `scalar(@sqlArray)` elements numbered from `0` to `@sqlArray-1` (aka `$#sqlArray`), but you access one further.

---

When you want to remove elements from an array, consider `grep`.

```perl
@sqlArray = grep { $_ ne 'factura.sql' } @sqlArray
   if $company ne 'Geeks';
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> my $count = scalar @sqlArray ;
> ```

This gives you the number of elements in `@sqlArray`.

> ```
> or $index==$count
> ```

But then you use it as though it's the last index in the array. It's not - it's one position off the end of the array (as Perl array indexes start from 0). And if you try to look at elements beyond the end of an array, Perl will give you `undef`.

Every Perl array has an associated scalar variable that will give you the last index in the array. For an array called `@sqlArray`, that variable is called `$#sqlArray`.

So you can remove your `$count` variable completely and use this instead:

```
$index++ until $sqlArray [$index] eq 'factura.sql' or $index==$#sqlArray;
```